# Get cell value from datagridview after applying custom cell formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView

My code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == BaoDuong.DVThucHien)
    {
        e.Value = "BTWASECO";
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

//// Cell Click

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{  
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
}
```

I wanna get value "BTWASECO", but the result is: http://upanhtocdo.com/image.php?di=IM76

Comment: That is really strange, you should have gotten BTWASECO. Your code is correct i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value` has not been changed after formatting

try with `FormattedValue`

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString());
```